# WCF Rest JSON service 400 bad request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, bad-request

So i wrote my first WCF project, seems like its working using my browser and jquery, but then i wrote a client and things messed up a bit...
actually seems like everything i do with that client result in a 400 bad request response...
so i've read some posts and found out a good way to sort things up is using fiddler, and started picking around...

since fiddler can't identify my client, i've used my client to send the data directly to it...
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByOtHJSZT_GtNHZqTVZMdVVqZEU/edit?usp=sharing
you can see a screenshot here.

as i can see oly things that differs are the leack of some headers (that don't seems like really usefull to me) and one use content-type as application/jsonp the other text/html (wich i think is the main problem).
The bad thing is i've setted the content-type header before sending the request, but with no result, please notice that in the right panel you can still see application/json.
I'm getting confused.

```
    private void SendSelectedFile()
    {
        string url = "http://" + WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.HostAddress + "/Service1.svc/rest/PostFileToServer";
        string jsonMsg = "{\"fileContentAsBase64String\":\"" + this.textBox1.Text + "\",\"where\":\"D:\\Temp.dwg\"}";
        byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMsg);

        HttpWebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url)) as HttpWebRequest;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        wr.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
        //wr.TransferEncoding = "UTF-8";
        System.IO.Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
        rs.Write(buffer , 0, buffer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse response = wr.GetResponse();
    }
```

and this is the interface of the service

```
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/PostFileToServer"
    )]
    Boolean PostFileToServer(string fileContentAsBase64String, string where);
```

Comment: With REST, time to leave WCF, Web Api is much simpler

Comment: I see two requests in the screenshot that you linked, both with 200 response.  Where's the one that's returning the 400?

Comment: As i said the second request is directed to fiddler that always respond with a 200, fiddler is unable to intercept my normal request, would be nice to know why.
how can i implement a service using web API ? can you point me out? I love to keep things simple.

Comment: Seems that fiddler have some trubles intercepting request to "localhost" i've some problem changing how iis express behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code, and I narrowed the 400 down to the value that's being passed to your `where` member:

```
string jsonMsg = "{\"fileContentAsBase64String\":\"" + this.textBox1.Text + "\",\"where\":\"D:\\Temp.dwg\"}";
```

I'm guessing you're trying to pass the value `D:\Tempdwg`, but the backslash \T seems to be getting interpreted by the server as an escape sequence.  Try base64 encoding that value, or double escaping it `\\\\`

[image: WCF Trace shows that it had an error deserializing the JSON string, right around the character "T"]

Comment: damn i got right there right now too, i think i'll need to urlencode it, i'll examine the fiddler raw request to see if chrome urlencoded it

Comment: one double reverse solidus for JSON and one for c# i feel that stupid!
Thanks so much!
BTW: how did you got there?
I enabled .net source stepping, and i don't love it so much.

Comment: I enabled [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).  There's a tool called SVCTraceViewer, found in your Microsoft SDK folder, that can be used to view the traces. I'll attach a sample screenshot to my solution